# Is it possible to process unstructured data(multi-line web logs) using Apache beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have java Regex code that reads multiple lines of my unstructured web log file and generates a json data.

Log file looks like below,

```
[2018-03-06 09:00:44,111] line1
[2018-03-06 09:00:46,236] line2
[2018-03-06 09:01:07,503] line3
[2018-03-06 09:01:20,097] line4
```

Now, I'm trying perform this conversion within dataflow pipeline. However, I did not find a way to read/process multiple lines together. Can someone help me to process multi-line web log file using dataflow?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Python or Java?

Comment: I'm using java SDK

Comment: Try `pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from(<path-to-file>))`. It will return a `PCollection`, where each element of the `PCollection` is one line of the file.

Comment: @ArjunKay I'm aware of it. In my case, multiple lines together makes a meaningful set. So i need a method or steps to process multiple lines together.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. It would be best to update the logging application to log a single line per message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataflow/Apache beam reads one line at a time and it cannot process multiple lines together. Hence I have a written a process to convert multiple line file to single line with delimiters and then passed as an input to Dataflow pipeline.